# HTML get value of select popoulated by PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, html, events, dom

I have a view that that I have written in HTML and PHP that is like the following:

```
<select name="category" id="_category" class="_cateogry"  onchange="submitTheForm() >
    option value="">Please select</option>
<?php foreach ($categories as $contents ) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $contents->id;?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $contents->name;?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

Now, I want to get `<?php echo $contents->name;?>` when the onChange function is called.

I tried to resolve it unsuccessfully in JS, and here is the JS code that I attempted:

```
function submitTheForm () {
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('_category');
    var selected = selectedElem.options[selectedElem.selectedIndex];
    console.log(selected.text);
}
```

I want to console.log the selected `<?php echo $contents->name;?>` when the onchange function is called.

Comment: Did you realize about this `onchange="submitTheForm('"`? and this `function submitTheForm{`?

Comment: `selectedElem` should be `selectedElement` or the other way around. It should be the same.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: hey @Ele I updated the code. Sorry, I was copy pasting and abstracting out the unnecessary information, and typo'ed there. It looks the way it should now.

Comment: _Just a small note_ All your dropdown items have got the `selected="selected"` attribute set ???

Comment: No. making another edit. I was just trying too many things, at the end of which, I just copy-pasted the last part of the code here to look for solutions. I should be more careful with my edits. Thank you for pointing out, @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing `"` after the javascript function and your code could be modified a little like this - to use `event` rather than rely upon names or ids

```
<select name="category" id="_category" class="_cateogry" onchange="submitTheForm(event)" >
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $contents ) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $contents->id;?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $contents->name;?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>

function submitTheForm( event ) {
    var value=event.target.value;
    var text=event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log('%s -> %s',value,text);
}
```

Comment: Hey @RamRaider , This is the only solution that seemed to work. I am going to implement this code into my code. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<select name="category" id="_category" class="_cateogry" onChange="submitTheForm(this);" >
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>

<script>
    function submitTheForm(sel)
    {
        console.log(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
    }
</script>
```

You can do as per below

```
    // select box code whch one you have alredy
    <select name="category" id="_category" class="_cateogry" onChange="submitTheForm(this);" >
    <option value="">Please select</option>
<?php foreach ($categories as $contents ) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $contents->id;?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $contents->name;?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

//Javascript code to get selected options text value

```
<script>
    function submitTheForm(sel)
    {
        console.log(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `addEventListener` to bind the event `change`.

*This is an alternative.*

You can get the `value` and `text` using the context `this`.

```js
document.getElementById('_category').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
});
```

```html
<select name="category" id="_category" class="_cateogry">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1595">Ele</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery easily rather than javascript:

```
function submitTheForm () {

   var optionName =  jQuery('#_category option:selected').text();

    alert(optionName);
}
```